# Будут ли работать java приложения, если установить jdk86 вместо jdk64?

Tags: java

У меня Win 10 x64.
Вопрос, что будет, если закачать jdk для x86 (32bit) на свою систему ? Какие теоретически сбои/проблемы могут возникнуть ?

Comment: Ну зачем тебе нужен jdk x86 качай х64 .
По сути оно вообще не должно установится.

Comment: Как-то вообще все попутано. Для работы приложений ставят не JDK, а JRE. Хотя, у военных вот свои причуды, они бы везде ставили JDK. Военные - вообще рассадник cowboy-кодеров с точки зрения гражданских)) Ладно. Теоретически. с нативными библиотеками (JNI) может быть проблема. Если в проекте 32-битная библиотека, то JRE x64 не сможет ее загрузить, и дело не в ОС, а именно в библиотеке. Было на практике.

Comment: Меньше памяти сможете использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проблемы с JNI, если используете.
2. Может вообще не установится
3. Возможна просадка по производительности в многопоточных приложениях (из-за особенности трединга на разно разрядных системах, например volatile long на 64bit не требует синхронизации, а на 32bit требует, так как он превышает размер регистра на 32х битной системе.